# many - to many relationship handling issue in entity framework

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I've got table

**Tourists**

1. Tourist_ID

   2.Name

---

**Extra_Charges**

1. Extra_Charge_ID
2. Description

---

**Toutist_Extra_Charges**

1. Tourist_Extra_Charge_ID - primary key
2. Tourist_ID - foreign key
3. Extra_Charge_ID - foreign key

---

I  try to make this sql query using entity framework ent

```
    "Select Tourist.Name, Extra_Charges.Extra_Charge_Description, FROM Tourist

LEFT JOIN TOURIST_EXTRA_CHARGES on Tourist.Tourist_ID = TOURIST_EXTRA_CHARGES.Tourist_ID 
LEFT Join EXTRA_CHARGES on TOURIST_EXTRA_CHARGES.Extra_Charge_ID = EXTRA_CHARGES.Extra_Charge_ID
WHERE Tourist.Tourist_ID=86
```

I want  to get the name of the tourist with id=86(event if he doesn't have extra_charges) AND IF HE DOES HAVE EXTRA_CHARGES - THE DESCRIPTION OF THE EXTRA_CHARGE

As I'm new to entity framework I tried the following

```
foreach (var tourist in db2.Tourist.Include("TOURIST_EXTRA_CHARGES").Include("EXTRA_CHARGES").Where(x=>x.Tourist_ID==86))
                  {
                      lblproba.Text+="Name" + tourist.Name_kir+" Description" + tourist.TOURIST_EXTRA_CHARGES.//don't have access to extra_charges table


                  }
```

But when I type tourist.TOURIST_EXTRA_CHARGES I don't have access to extra_charges table and its Description column

---

**EDIT:**

I read that to use the entity framework mapping with many-to-manyrelationship i should delete my column TOURIST_EXTRA_CHARGE_ID  and make compository primary key. 
But when I did that - and made new edmx model - I now can't see my Tourist_Extra_Charges table. 
And nomatter how many times i created the model - this table didn't occur in the model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I now can't see my Tourist_Extra_Charges table

That's expected for the link table in a many-to-many relationship and you don't need this table as an entity.

Your `Tourist` entity should now have a collection `EXTRA_CHARGES` and you can perform your query like so:

```
var tourist = db2.Tourist
    .Include("EXTRA_CHARGES")
    .SingleOrDefault(t => t.Tourist_ID == 86);

if (tourist != null)
{
    lblproba.Text += "Name "
        + tourist.Name_kir
        + " Description "
        + string.Join(", ", tourist.EXTRA_CHARGES.Select(e => e.Description));
}
```

I have replaced the `foreach` loop by `SingleOrDefault` because you are querying by the primary key which can only have one result (or none). The `EXTRA_CHARGES.Select(e => e.Description)` extracts the description from each extra charge and returns a new collection of strings. `string.Join` concats all those descriptions in the collection together and separates them by a comma.

Answer (score 0):

Your database structure is wrong. If you need to link 2 tables using many2many relationship, you must add one more table, so called a "bridge" table containing 2 PKs from your other 2 tables. And when you have it, the EF will automatically resolve it as a relation property as "many2many"